# Constexpr static member definition

Tags: c++, c++11

In my code I have classes with the following structure (I use c++11):

```
class Foo {
public:
static constexpr double A = 3.0;
//....other....
};
```

Sometimes I have linker error because the static variable is not defined in cpp file. But not always. I don't understand the rule here, when is it needed to declare the static field in cpp and when not?

Comment: *"Sometimes ... But not always."*  Do you have an example that consistently reproduces the error?  What you have shown looks correct to me.

Comment: This question has been closed but the other one doesn't reply to the question. Reading the reply it seems you need to always declare the out of class variable before c++17, but it's wrong because I have several examples where I didn't do it and it works.

Comment: @greywolf82 - Did you skim the bit where it says ODR use?

Comment: If including the header in more than once place, you need to put the definition in the cpp file, otherwise you're effectively defining the variable twice, and will get a linker error along the lines of multiple defined symbols. #pragma once will prevent you from _declaring_ a variable multiple times, but not from _defining_ it multiple times. I suspect the times it has worked will be where the header is only included once throughout the codebase.